# Spring-boot config server application throw exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am running simple demo of spring cloud config server on Mac OS X. Application has native as active profile and use local folder for config files instead of git. When I launch application it throws exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/api/TransportConfigCallback
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:818)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:804)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:790)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.test.docker.DemoConfigServerApplication.main(DemoConfigServerApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 24 more
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-config-server</name>
    <description>Demo config project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: demo-config
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: file:///Users/macosx/cloud/config-local
```

I ran similar example on windows 7 machine in my workplace and it worked fine. Does anyone have any idea what could be problem?

Thanks

Comment: Clear your local repository, probably a borked jar. Run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` after that rebuild your app to download the dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, it solves the problem. When I ran command in project directory it shows error in aws sdk in .m2 directory 'Non-parseable POM /Users/macosx/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-pom/1.11.125/aws-java-sdk-pom-1.11.125.pom'. I deleted was folder and ran command again and I was able to build and run application. If you can post this as answer I will accept it. Many thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when those kind of errors pop up something went wrong when maven downloaded the dependencies. To solve this clear your local repository from the borked dependencies.

You have basically two ways of solving this

1. Bluntly remove the full `~/.m2/repository` directory, removing all local dependencies
2. The more subtle `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove all project dependencies from the `~/.m2/repository` directory.

After that just rebuild your application `mvn package` to download the dependencies again.

Comment: This answer already helped me resolving several problems of "ClassNotFound" and other misleading errors messages due to repository conflicts.

Answer (score -2):

In the last line of application.yaml use searchLocations instead of search-locations.

Comment: I have tried using searchLocations but still same exception is coming. In spring-tool-suite suggestion search-locations shows up instead of searchLocations thats why I used search-locations.

Comment: For Spring Boot `searchLocations` and `search-locations` are the same.